# Python returns length of 2 for single non-ascii character string

Tags: python, string, non-ascii-characters

I am trying to get the span of selected words in a string. When working with the `İ` character, I noticed the following behavior of `Python`:

```
len("İ")
Out[39]: 1

len("İ".lower())
Out[40]: 2

# when `upper()` is applied, the length stays the same
len("İ".lower().upper())
Out[41]: 2
```

Why does the length of the upper and lowercase value of the same character differ (that seems very confusing/undesired to me)?

Does anyone know if there are other characters for which that will happen?
Thank you!

**EDIT:**

On the other hand for e.g. `Î` the length stays the same:

```
len('Î')
Out[42]: 1

len('Î'.lower())
Out[43]: 1
```

Comment: *Does anyone know if there are other characters for which that will happen?* That İ is the only one, currently, as far as I know. For a lower character that does the other way (becomes longer after str.upper) there are hundreds, the most well-known of which is ß

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I was not aware of thes behaviour either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `'İ'` in lowercase is `'i̇'`, which has 2 characters

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.name('İ')
'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE'
>>> unicodedata.name('İ'.lower()[0])
'LATIN SMALL LETTER I'
>>> unicodedata.name('İ'.lower()[1])
'COMBINING DOT ABOVE'
```

One character is a combining dot that your browser might render overlapped with the last quote, so you may not be able to see it. But if you copy-paste it into your python console, you should be able to see it.

---

If you try:

```
print('i̇'.upper())
```

you should get

```
İ
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! The `unicodedata.name('İ')` method is very interessting indeed. The question that I still have difficulties to understand, is why that happens? Isn't this a undesired behaviour?

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue is that a lower case character for that symbol is undefined in ASCII.

The `.lower()` function probably performs a fixed offset to the ASCII number associated with the character, since that works for the English alphabet.

Comment: This is unicode - has nothing to do with ASCII encoding. And that's not what `str.lower` actually does..